# PHP Array, always by reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Is there a way to create a PHP array which always treated by reference without having to use the `&` operator?

For instance:

```
$a = array_by_ref('a', 'b', 'c');
$b = $a;
$b[] = 'd';
```

should result in both `$a` and `$b` being equal to:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: Using the & symbol involves less typing :)

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest against doing anything to get around the usage of the & operator, mostly for code readability. Using & makes it obvious that you're dealing with a reference. Remove it (using any method) could potentially cause confusion to others reading your code (and even sometimes yourself given that there's a length of time from writing to re-reading.. Not that that's ever happened to me of course ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SPL is available, there is the [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class:

```
$a = new ArrayObject(array('a', 'b', 'c'));
$b = $a;
$b[] = 'd';
```

These are still wrapper objects though; to get their primitive array equivalents you have to use the object's `getArrayCopy()` method. Also bear in mind that it can be quite slow, particularly when you iterate through its elements.

Comment: I think `ArrayObject::getArrayCopy()` might be preferable to casting.

Comment: @Mchl: Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayObject` doesn't go along with `array_map`, `array_reduce`, and similar functions that expect a real array as an input. If you want an array property of an object to be copied by reference, wrap it with any kind of object:

```
class Test
{
    private $array;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->array = (object) ['array' => []];
    }

    // we also need to return it by reference
    public function &getMyArray()
    {
        return $this->array->array;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$test = new Test();
$test->getMyArray()[] = 'Hello';
$another = clone $test;
$another->getMyArray()[] = 'Fucking';
$third = clone $another;
$third->getMyArray()[] = 'World!';
unset($test->getMyArray()[1]);

var_dump($test->getMyArray() === $third->getMyArray());
var_dump(implode(" ", $test->getMyArray()));
var_dump(gettype($test->getMyArray()));
```

Sample output:

```
bool(true)
string(12) "Hello World!"
string(5) "array"
```